# I can’t connect to my Azure VM

Tags: azure, linux-networking, centos7

After I used this command:

```
ifdown eth0
```

can't connect to my VM (CentOS 6) with ssh on cloud Microsoft azure. 
How can I fix it?

Comment: You seem to be asking why shutting down your only NIC is causing a loss of connectivity - what did you think running this command (`ifdown`) would have achieved?

Answer (score 2):

Well, of course if you brought down the network you can't reach the VM anymore. What else were you expecting? :)

Just reboot the VM from the Azure management portal; the network should start automatically.

Comment: hey Massimo , 
i tried to rebbot the vm  and i got this error:vm has not reported status for vm agent or extensions. please verify the vm has a running vm agent,and can establish outbound connections to azure storage.

Comment: Looks like you brought down the network in a somewhat more persistent way than `ifdown eth0`, then...